# Clean up Known javascript malware on wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, malware

Hi one of my wordpress website is affected by malware when I checked at https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/

It says
Known javascript malware. Details: http://sucuri.net/malware/malware-entry-mwspamseo
 `document.write('<' + 'di' + 'v sty' + 'le="position: absolute; l' + 'eft: -1835px; t' + 'op' + ': -2665px;">');`

How should I clean this? And i dont see this javascript anywhere in my theme files. I tried disabling all the plugins but no use. Please help

Comment: It's in your database if at all present. How secure/trustworthy is that testing website?

Answer (score 0):

While you could try to comb through all of the files, you should really re-install WordPress, re-install your theme, restore your database to a clean state, and make sure you lock everything down to prevent the issue from happening again. Re-installing is the only way to be sure you're getting rid of everything bad.

Read more about ["hardening" WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) and [what to do when you've been hacked](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) in the Codex.

Comment: I re-installed the wordpress and all the plugins. Also I imported all the posts and pages manually. I just wanted to understand how to prevent this in future, also its not easy to re-install everything again and again. Thanks for reading and discussing.